# Enter a hyperlink without login and redirect to ReturnUrl with datetime (hour and minute) after login

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to redirect to a ReturnUrl which contains datetime, including hour and minute. This datetime is a parameter to filter and display the most recent items. Although it has no problem when I directly enter `localhost:59889/Home/Index/?parameterName=yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM AM` if I have already logged in. However, if I go to this link before logging in and then enter my username and password, an error will occur that the returnUrl has the wrong format. After debugging, the code stops at RedirectFromLoginPage().

I am developing an email sender application. The email contains a hyperlink pointing to a website written by ASP.NET MVC.  Because users have not logged in when they click the hyperlink in the email, after they log in, I want them to go directly to the webpage in my hyperlink (with datetime parameter).

```
HomeController:Controller


[HTTPPOST]
ActionResult Index(params){
...
RedirectFromLoginPage()
...
//get the items after a certain time, using EF framework Lambda expression
...
return null
}
```

After trial and error, I find that it is not an encoding problem with spaces, because `Sat, 05 Nov 2019` format can work. If I add `HH:MM` (hour and minute) to the returnUrl, it will always give me an error.

For example, when the returnUrl is `localhost:59889/Home/Index?date=06/09/2018 11:00 AM`, it doesn't work if I want to redirect from the login page to the destination link. But if I have already logged in and then enter the link with the above parameter, it does work.

Now, could anyone please tell me how to add hour and minute in the date parameter, put them to returnUrl so that if I enter the link and then log in, it can go to the correct address without errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely that you're including the `:` character in the URL.

Try serialising into a more URL friendly format such as a UTC timestamp integer or URL encoding the string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! Tomorrow I will try to use timestamp.